# How do I delete files based on subversion?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a folder named "y", that is not kept in version control. I have a folder "x" that is under version control. I want to copy `y` into `x`, because then I can use `Tortoisesvn` `Check for Modifications` command on folder `x`

I can then assume that every file/folder that reads `Non-versioned` or `Ignored` can safely be deleted. Since my WC has been working fine for a year without them.

How do I get a list of files marked by Subversion as added to create my batch script?

## Update.

I've gotten pretty far, I think I just need a way to automate this.

I copied y into x. I ran check for modifications.  I can right click the dialog and copy paths to clipboard.  I only select the Unversioned or ignored files.

I paste the paths into a batch file. I use some find and replace magic to create this.

```
XCOPY www.root\* www.root.backup /I /Q /R /S /E
CD www.root
DEL "Appraisals\*.*" /q /s
DEL "jobs\Backup\*.*" /q /s
DEL "New\Portability\BACKUP\*.*" /q /s
DEL "Footer\Codes\*.*" /q /s
DEL "QL\Commercial\*.*" /q /s
DEL "images\Discard\*.*" /q /s
DEL "Dup SH Pages\*.*" /q /s
DEL "ExtensionRequest\*.*" /q /s
DEL "ExtFile\*.*" /q /s
DEL "Ad\Include\*.*" /q /s
DEL "Bio\Include\*.*" /q /s
DEL "Contact\Include\*.*" /q /s
```

## Update #2

I work better with analogies and examples, so here is the scenario and what I want the outcome to be.

Please imagine I have the a very simple trunk in my repo.  It has only one file `code.txt`  I make my changes to that file, commit them back to the repo. After changes are commited to the repo I export only this file from the repo to Production.

Now imagine some other developers come along and don't talk to me. They copy directly out to the production server all kinds of files.

`copy of code.txt`
`bob's copy of code.txt_backup`
`copy of copy of copy of bob's copy of code.txt_backup.backup`

Now Imagine, I realize this, and decide to protect their code in subverion.  I add it to my repo and commit.  Now over time I realize that `copy of copy of copy of bob's copy of code.txt_backup.backup` is actually part of production and the other two files are garbage.

I delete the files `copy of code.txt`,`bob's copy of code.txt_backup` from my WC and commit.  I also make a tiny change to `code.txt`. I commit.

Now when I compare to previous revision and do an export Tortoise will export the changed file(s).

So Now I have two files orphaned on production.  I want a script to delete them from production based on the fact that they are not in the HEAD of Subversion.

Now imagine if you had 5300 files and folders.
....Whew.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with a new suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you only need to copy the content of y into checked-out x.

Then, open x with windows explorer. Since you have tortoise svn installed on your PC, the files not under version will be flagged with a blue icon, those modified with a red icon and those not modified with a green icon.

Is that what you are looking for?

**EDIT**

I just had another idea:

1. Create a copy of Y.
2. Loop through all files f of X.
3. Delete all f in Y.

In the end Y will contain the files not in X, which is what you want, no? Then you can delete them from X after adding Y to X.

Comment: That's the first part.  Now, I want to generate a script that is a list of all the blue icons, to apply to y  "DELETE THESE FILES NOW!"

Comment: @Doug Unfortunately, I am not really sure this is possible, unless you analyze the .svn files created in X. I think it is a manual job to do. May be someone else has a better suggestion.